# Adicionar elemento após outro com jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como posso adicionar outra tag `<li> ... </li>` após a última com **Jquery**? 
Tenho instalado um plugin "Jquery Custom", e o faria por lá.

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 social-media style-1">
   <h3 class="widget-title">Permaneça conectado</h3>
   <ul class="social-link">
      <li class="icon-facebook">
         <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="icon-instagram">
         <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/">
            <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="icon-google-plus">
         <a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/communities/114812437665613081264">
            <i class="fa fa-flickr"></i>
         </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das soluções será utilizar a função **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** do Jquery.

Exemplo com o seu código:

```
$('.social-link').append('<li class="icon-facebook"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>');
```

'.social-link' é o *container* onde quer adicionar e o que está dentro do parentêsis é o conteúdo que vai ser adicionado. (atenção ás aspas e plicas)

O **append** adiciona sempre no fim do contentor.

Cumprimentos

Comment: Resolvi a situação com a ajuda de vocês, gratidão.

Answer (score 4):

Bom, consegui assim, utilizando [.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/).

**Exemplo:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('<li class="icon-youtube"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com.br/"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>Inserido com jQuery</a></li>').insertAfter('li.icon-google-plus');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 social-media style-1">
  <h3 class="widget-title">Permaneça conectado</h3>
  <ul class="social-link">
    <li class="icon-facebook">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        1
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon-instagram">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/">
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
        2
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon-google-plus">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/communities/114812437665613081264">
        <i class="fa fa-flickr"></i>
        3
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```